# How to make website scroll down

Tags: html, css, web

I have made an image 100% height and width. But I had some headings and paragraphs underneath. When viewing my website I cannot scroll down further to see the headings and paragraphs? Also, I want a small burger navigation bar over the top of the image, at the top. But since making the image full screen, this has been "pushed away" as well?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8"/>
    <title>XXXXX</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="s.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <nav id = "burger">
    </nav>

    <section id = "top_image">
        <img src="images/bg1.png"/>
    </section>

    <section id = "description">
        <article>
            <header>
                <h4>DESCRIPTION</h4>
            </header>
            <p>
                XXXXXX<br />
                XXXXXXXXXXX<br />
                XXXXXXXX
            </p>
            <p>
                XXXXXXX<br />
                XXXXXXX<br />
                cXXXX<br />
                XXXXXXX
            </p>
        </article>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Does adding `overflow: scroll` style to `body` not work?

Answer (score 1):

When you make the image (or in this case, all img tags) `position: absolute`, you take them out of the page layout flow. That means everything else renders like that image isn't there. Your menu bar and paragraphs are there underneath the image, but you can't see them. If you make the paragraph text long enough it will poke out the bottom. If you want the image to be part of the page layout, get rid of the `position: absolute.`

Add this temporarily to your CSS to see what's going on:

```
#description {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

You'll suddenly see your text on top of the image.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't that things are being pushed down, the issue is that your image is covering every other element on the page because you've positioned it absolutely. You can't scroll because there's nothing to scroll to.

If you are trying to use the image as a background image, then you should code it as a background image.

```
body {
    background:url('http://placehold.it/1024x768');
    background-size:cover;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jzv3vo3/1/)

Comment: I do not want it as the bg image for the whole webpage. Only the bg for the size of 1 screen on loading. I then want to scroll down the length of another screen and have another one and so forth?

Comment: Take a look at [fullPage JS](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage), it sounds like what you're after.

Comment: Thank you. Although, out of interest, I would like to know how it would be coded without it?